# Sharing a variable between two winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a winforms application.

I have a textbox on one form (call F1) and when a button is clicked on this form (call F2), it launches another form.

On F2, I want to set a string via a textbox (and save it to a variable in the class), and then when I close this form, the string will appear in a label in F1.

So I am basically sharing variables between both forms. However, I can't get this to work correctly. How would this code look?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would add a new property to form2.  Say it's for a phone number.  Then I'd add a friend property m_phone() as string to form 2.  After showing an instance of form2 but before closing it, you can refer to the property m_phone in form1's code.

It's an additional level of indirection from Matthew Abbott's solution.  It doesn't expose form2 UI controls to form1.

**EDIT**

e.g.:

```
public string StoredText
{
    get;
    private set;
}
```

inside the set you can refer to your UI control, like return textBox1.text.  Use the get to set the textbox value from an earlier load.

And:

```
public string GetSomeValue()
{
    var form = new F2();
    form.ShowDialog();

    return form.StoredText;
}
```

Just ensure that `StoredText` is populated (or not, if appropriate) before the form is closed.

Comment: Totally agree, I should have known that, you should really provide properties to access the values instead of exposing UI fields.

I've edited your answer and +1 for the property.

Comment: just curious- why public over friend?  I wouldn't think this property would need to be read outside the .sln

Comment: In my specific case, it wouldn't have to be. Anyway, this worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

Are you showing the second form as a dialog, this is probably the best way to do it.  If you can avoid doing shared variables, you could do the following:

```
public string GetSomeValue()
{
    var form = new F2();
    form.ShowDialog();

    return form.TextBox1.Text;
}
```

And called in code:

```
Label1.Text = GetSomeValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the most efficient way of approaching, but you could create a class called DB (database). Inside this class, create variables like

`public static bool test` or `public static bool[] test = new bool[5];`

In your other forms, you can just create an instance. `DB db = new DB();` then grab the information using `db.test = true/false`. This is what I've been doing and it works great.

Sorry, I'm only like a year late.